# In jmeter: getting Error invoking bsh method: eval

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;  String path=FileServer.getFileSer . . . '' : Attempt to access property on undefined variable or class name 2022-01-27 19:50:51,923 WARN o.a.j.e.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of:` import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;  String path=FileServer.getFileSer . . . '' : Attempt to access property on undefined variable or class name

JMETER BEANSHELL CODE: (Beanshell post processor)
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
String path=FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();

```
var1= vars.get("userid");      
var2= vars.get("username");
var3= vars.get("userfullname");
var4= ${exam_id};
```

f = new FileOutputStream("C://apache-jmeter-5.4.1/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/Script4.csv",true);
p = new PrintStream(f);

this.interpreter.setOut(p);
p.println(var1+ "," +var2 + "," +var3 + "," +var4);

f.close();

Answer (score 0):

1. Change this line:

   ```
   var4= ${exam_id};
   ```

   to this one:

   ```
   var4= vars.get("exam_id");
   ```
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it worth considering migrating to Groovy.
3. If you run this code with more than 1 thread (virtual user) you will face a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) resulting in data corruption when multiple threads will be writing into the same file. JMeter provides [`sample_variables` property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) allowing to write variables values to the .jtl results file, if you need to store the data in a separate file - go for [Flexible File Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)

Comment: I have used 70 thread count, but only 69 are written into the file, and 2 exceptions are received.
So, I think this "var4= vars.get("exam_id");" will not help out.

Comment: can anyone help?